# how to change css of a tag on the basis of data?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, rendering

I am building a spa in vuejs and I want to change the color of my text on the basis of data I recieved,if i get pending status it should be grey and if submitted then green and if rejected then red and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vue comoponent, you can have the data and computed methods for status like this.

```
...

data() {
  return {
    // This status can be "rejected", "pending" and "submitted" for example.
    // Change the value of this in order to change the color.
    status: "pending"
  }
},

computed: {
   statusColor() {
     return {
       "text-grey": this.status === "pending",
       "text-green": this.status === "submitted",
       "text-red": this.status === "rejected"
     }
   }
}

...
```

The computed method `statusColor` returns the class with the given status data, so yon need to define each class in your css.

```
.text-grey {
  color: "grey";
}
.text-green {
  color: "green";
}
.text-red {
  color: "red";
}
```

And in your HTML, you can bind the data (status) to `:class` to switch the style.

```
<div>
  <p v-bind:class="statusColor">Status</p>
</div>
```

https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: how do i bind the value of the p tag using v-model ?

Comment: `v-model` is almost only for input. If you want to show the content of data into p tag, you can do that with a format called mustache: `<p>{{ status }}<p>`

Comment: yes i am using that my query was how do i keep on changing the value of status:'pending ' etc

Comment: what do you mean keeping changed specifically?

Comment: like if i have 5  tasks and then there statuses are different.

like: a : submitted,b:pending,c:rejected

Comment: Ok. In that kind of case, you will probably want to pass the status of each task. Then you can use `methods`, not computed methods, because `methods` can take arguments. You can use it in binding like `v-bind:class="statusColor(task.status)"`

Comment: I added this statusColor(e) {
           if(e == 'submitted'){
            return ".text-red"
           }
       } but it still not rendering

Comment: You need to return object, not string. See the content of `statusColor` in my answer.